# How to sort with variable field?

Tags: vba, ms-access

Sort with variable does not work in VBA.

In the code `DoCmd.SetOrderBy Field1` does not work since Field1 is Variable. VBA accepts the code but does not sort at the end.

table_1 contains source data like name and age, dress, school, etc.

We want to copy its data to Table_2.

I want to sort

- first by age then copy names
- second by address
- third by school

At the end I got original order.

```
Sub AA()

    Count1 = Table_2.Fields.Count
    For I = 2 To Count1 - 1
        Field1 = Table_2.Fields(I).Name   'for example Filed(2) is "Age"
        Field2 = Field1 & " DESC"

        Table_1.Open "select * from Table_1", , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimisti
        DoCmd.SetOrderBy Field1    ' Here VBA accept this code line but acutally not sort the table by Filed(2)="Age".
        Table_1.MoveFirst
        Table_2.Fields.Item(Name).Value = Table_1!Name   'Here it copy orginal first record, not record after sorting (i.e Name filed)
    Next I
'------------------------------------

        ' Here I try other way to sort
        ' But Also  VBA not accept below statment
Table_1.Open "select * from Table_1 order by " & [Field1], , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimisti

End Sub
```

Comment: what is `table_1 and table_2`? you canot select from another recordset. Please declare your variables properly.

Comment: The issue Sort with variable not work in VBA. in code: DoCmd.SetOrderBy Field1 ,, not work since Field1 is Variable. VBA accpet the code but not sort at the end.

Comment: please edit your question and add more information what you are trying to do and the outcome.

Comment: table_1 is table contain source data like name and age, dress,school,etc, . we want to copy its data to Table_2, first I want o sort by age then copy names, second sort by address, third by school, like this.. but at the end I got same original order, sort not done

Answer (score 0):

Dont put brackets around a string, that's for field names within a string.

```
Table_1.Open "SELECT * FROM Table_1 ORDER BY " & Field1, , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Does `Field1` contain a space in it?

if so, try:

```
Table_1.Open "SELECT * FROM Table_1 ORDER BY [" & Field1 & "]", , adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

Comment: Also that not accepted, give error 3001 'Arguments are of the wrong type or out of acceptable range…'

Comment: so `adLockOptimisti` isn't a typo?

Comment: Does `Field1` contain a space in it?

Comment: Field1  not contain space in it.